# Change resolution of text console

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, nvidia, console, resolution

I bought an xps laptop with a 4k screen.
Because of this, the font-size of my text consoles (Ctrl+Alt+[F1-F6]) are quite tiny. So I tried to change the resolution by editing `/etc/default/grub` like it is adviced by many tutorials.
Right now it looks like this:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"

# Changes -------------------------------------------------------------------

# Set resolution of text consoles
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=1024x768
```

This settings doesn't change the resolution of my text consoles.
When I use the attribute `nomodeset` (`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nomodeset"`) the text consoles are displayed with the specified resolution, but then my GUI is realy slow, has the same resolution **and I even can't log into my account.**

So how do I get it work (use specified text console resolution, different GUI resolution and GUI not broken)?

I run Ubuntu 15.10 and has a Nvidia GeForce GT 750M.
I am new to Linux so please keep it simple :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: how about just setting the console font to a larger size using setfont?

Answer (score 4):

I have a similar problem, and I found that setfont works fine. Try:

```
$ setfont Uni2-VGA28x16
```

The list of available console fonts are under: `/usr/share/consolefonts` (for my ubuntu install)